# Tumblr video size

Tags: html, tumblr

Please I am using a tumblr theme and the space allowed for a video post on the home page it's the same when I click the permalink. The space it's good for the home page but it's too little for the permalink, so what can I do to set the permanlink video space bigger without changing the video size on the home page ?

Here is the HTML code: [Concept](http://www.tumblr.com/theme/18547)
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include to your theme [**Fitvid.js**](http://fitvidsjs.com/) on *`permalink`* pages.

> A lightweight, easy-to-use jQuery plugin for fluid width video embeds.

Change size of video changing size of video-wrapper, and **FitVid** will resize video.

**UPD:**

### Step-by-step instruction:

1. [**Download**](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitVids.js/downloads) source code of *Fitvid.js* from github;
2. Upload to Tumblr file hosting with [**static file uploader**](http://www.tumblr.com/themes/upload_static_file) and copy(save) the *url* of uploaded file;
3. Open [Customize page](http://www.tumblr.com/customize/) of your blog in new page;
4. Press **'Edit HTML'** button;
5. Find `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>` string;
6. Paste after it this string: `<script type="text/javascript" src="FITVIDURL"></script>` - where `FITVIDURL` is saved url from step #2;
7. Wrap resulting string from step #6 with this `if` statement, like this:
   `{block:PermalinkPage} STRING from prev. step {/block:PermalinkPage}` -- this statement will include this library only on *permalink* pages;

#### Further reading:

- [Fitvid.js readme](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitVids.js)
- [How to create a custom HTML theme](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes/) via [@Tumblr](http://twitter.com/tumblr)
- [Unofficial Tumblr Theme Guide](http://disattention.com/labs/tumblr/theme-guide/) via [@bobdiaes](http://twitter.com/bobdiaes)

Comment: Please can you check the main post I edited it, I gave you the wrong theme... @Vladimir Starkov

Comment: @Kevin theme doesn't matter, try to include script. It should help you anyway

Comment: I'm completely newbie can you please indicate me the step (English is not my native language)...And by the way I'm using [imgur](http://imgur.com) album embed code (but I don't think that is a problem) @Vladimir Starkov

Comment: @Kevin can you wait about 5-6 hours? after it I will can show what to do

Comment: For sure... so see you in about 5-6 hours @Vladimir Starkov

Comment: @Kevin just added step by step instruction

Comment: @VladimirStarkov is it possible to set this up for tumblr hosted videos? Thanks!

Comment: I think, it is possible. You should try

Comment: @VladimirStarkov I did and I can't seem to get it to work, would you know how?

Comment: @MinaSimic try to ask a new question on SO with details